# Prevent traffic from specific IP from routing through OpenVPN

Tags: pi-3, vpn, iptables

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 as a WiFi access point, which routes all traffic through the `tun0` interface/OpenVPN. However, I'd like to be able to route traffic from a device with the IP `172.24.1.126` on the network through `eth0` interface to bypass the VPN. I have tried marking packets, and routing those packets using a table with a rule to route through `eth0` as follows:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 172.24.1.126 -j MARK --set-mark 11
ip rule add fwmark 11 table 3
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 table 3
```

However, even when `ip route get 8.8.8.8 from 172.24.1.126 iif eth0 mark 11` returned that it was being routed through `eth0`, the public IP of that device was still that of the VPN server.

The following is my kernel routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.18.10.5      128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.18.10.1      10.18.10.5      255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 tun0
10.18.10.5      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
108.61.228.73   192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
128.0.0.0       10.18.10.5      128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
172.24.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

My iptables rules are:

```
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

in order to route traffic from `wlan0` through the VPN.

Any ideas on how to route traffic from that local IP around the VPN would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Problem was that packets weren't being forwarded back through `wlan0` when sent through `eth0`, so they never reached the device. I needed to configure the same iptables rules above for `eth0` as well. What I ended up doing:

```
sudo ip rule add fwmark 3 table 3
sudo iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 172.24.1.126 -j MARK --set-mark 3
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 table 3
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```